# AngularJs compare strings inside ng-if doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to compare a string value inside `ng-if` but it doesn't work properly.

For example, i have this scope value to be compared with a string:

```
vm.val = 'abc'; //or vm.myval = 'afg';
```

And the `html` looks like this:

```
<div ng-if="vm.myval == 'abc'> Option abc </div>
<div ng-if="vm.myval == 'afg'> Option afg </div>
```

But the output is always the first option, Option abc. I even tried using `===` but the result is the same.

How can I compare this to an exact match of the strings?

Comment: is the controlleras = vm?

Answer (score 3):

If everything else is alright, you just forgot to close the quotes, try:

```
<div ng-if="vm.myval == 'abc'"> Option abc </div>
<div ng-if="vm.myval == 'afg'"> Option afg </div>
```